# Phoenix Localization

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm developing a multilingual application using the Phoenix Framework

So far, the router look like this:

```
scope "/:locale", App do
    pipe_through [:browser, :browser_session]

    get "/", PageController, :index

    get  "/otherpage", OtherpageController, :index
end

scope "/", App do

end
```

I used the plug in the docs :  http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/understanding-plug#section-module-plugs

And to make the "locale" persistent in the app, I used the custom action in the Phoenix.Controller module to do this:

```
def action(conn, _) do
    apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn), [conn,
                                    conn.params,
                                    conn.assigns.locale])
end
```

so now every time I generated a controller I should add the above custom action, and change every action in the new controller to inject the **locale**

```
def index(conn, _params, locale) do
    list = Repo.all(List)

    render conn, "index.html", list: list
end
```

There are two things that I'm struggling with:

**1 -** Is this the right way ? or I'm messing something ?

**2 -** And how to make the **scope "/"** to be redirect to **scope "/:locale"** with a default value like: **"en"** ?

**EDIT**

I like to have this url: "example.com/en"

Kayne

Comment: This might help http://sevenseacat.net/2015/12/20/i18n-in-phoenix-apps.html

Comment: Thanks Sasha, I checked it before but it does not answer my questions.

Comment: That's very interesting. Did have to deal with collation as well? I wonder how would solve that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Phoenix and Elixir myself but it seems to me a Plug would be the perfect solution for your second question. Use a Plug to modify the conn to for example redirect to `/:locale`. How to use Plugs to redirect is described [in the Phoenix documentation here](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/understanding-plug#section-function-plugs). I copied the redirect for localization plug part in the following:

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Plugs.Locale do
  import Plug.Conn

  @locales ["en", "fr", "de"]

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(%Plug.Conn{params: %{"locale" => loc}} = conn, _default) when loc in @locales do
    assign(conn, :locale, loc)
  end
  def call(conn, default), do: assign(conn, :locale, default)
end

defmodule HelloPhoenix.Router do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug HelloPhoenix.Plugs.Locale, "en"
  end
```

When it comes to redirecting with a Plug [this blog article](https://www.amberbit.com/elixir-cocktails/phoenix/handling-url-redirects-in-phoenix-with-plug/) is also a short and helpful resource.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Using a plug seems like a good choice.